# good way to return a promise in AngularJS, how to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have this example:

```
var lastTime = '';
$scope.loadEvents = function () {
   var items = listEvents();
    items.then(function (data) {
        lastTime = data;
    });
};


$scope.openModal = function (data) {
     //i want to use lastTime here;   
};
```

when i click on a button i am calling `openModal()` and in there i want to make sure that `data` is returned.

so i think i have to return a promise from the `loadEvents()` function

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *make sure you get the data from an async operation*, the best way to handle would be to return the promise from the source (chain it though) and use it in the `OpenModal`. This will make sure whenver you click on the modal the data will be returned always and there is no synchronization issue.

```
$scope.loadEvents = function () {
   var items = listEvents();
   return items.then(function (data) { //Make the loadEvents return a promise
       return data;  //return the data after any mapping or anything you may want to do
    });
};


$scope.openModal = function (data) {
     $scope.loadEvents().then(function(data){ //
         lastTime = data;
     });
};
```

In order to avoid multiple simultaneous call when the response has not yet come back from the server, you could return the same promise that was created earlier.

```
 var _cachedPromise;
 $scope.loadEvents = function () {
   var items = listEvents();
    //Actually you could chain all these together but for clarity steps have been broken down.
    if(_cachedPromise) return _cachedPromise;

    _cachedPromise = items.then(function (data) { //Make the loadEvents return a promise
       return data;  //return the data after any mapping or anything you may want to do
    });

    //Cleanup promise to make fresh calls.
    _cachedPromise.finally(function(){
        _cachedPromise = null;
    });

   return _cachedPromise;
};
```

But this caching promise logic you should ideally try to handle it in the service rather on the controller...